# How do I Split Application into a new Version for a different User Base?

Tags: visual-studio

We have a website application that stores data and pictures for a specific customer. We are about to release the same application for use by another customer. The second application will eventually be customized for the second customer. Eventually we hope to have several customers using their own versions of the application.

We are using ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2012. Should we:

1. clone the existing application and maintain separate code bases?
2. add a project to the existing solution for the new customer?

We have searched for an answer to but this seems to be a rare situation.

Thanks.

Comment: Maintaining different code bases wouldn't be desirable since bug fixes would then need to be made to all code bases for each customer rather than making the change once

Comment: Also, though IANAL, make sure you own the code before you go copy-pasting. Some clients can get picky if they find out they paid for the first version then you're using, out-of-the-box, on another client.

Comment: Good point. We do own the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think its rare at all.  SAP and Maximo use this a a businiess model. Same core but each package customized to the clients specifications. I have done this (on a much much smaller scale) with some of the programs that we have.

1. We always start a new project rather than just copy the old.  No telling what is in the old one that references the old client. Sort of embarasing when an About window that you forgot about is for someone elses company.
2. All the code, forms, reports that are customizeable should be in the project for that customer. All of the code, forms, reports that are standard should be in a library.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the scope of the application. I've had to do this internally with the company I'm working for; I wrote one solution for one company, then the sister company found out and wanted the same and had to implement it there.

I had a fairly small project to work on, so it was easy to make it universal (while also keeping things rooting from the same code base). All i did was:

- break out the unique setting [page title?] using `appSettings` or similar.
- add a new configuration to your solution. Then take advantage of the *.config migrations to:

  - set `connectionStrings`
  - specify `appSettings` values

When it comes to unique business logic, I had the luxury of using the *.config migrations (most of the data I gathered came from WCF endpoints of services local to the company)--so I lucked out. However, you could make generic interfaces within the app then break out implementation for each company in to separate libraries.